# Acceso por niveles de directorios con os.walk

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero acceder, con `os.walk` al primer nivel de un directorio. Por ejemplo, acceder a `root/B` sin llegar a acceder a `root/B/D.`

```
     root
     /|\
    / | \
   /  |  \
  A   B   C
     /     \
    /       \
   D         E
```

Con el siguiente código me lee todos los niveles:

```
for root, dir, files in os.walk(ruta): 
    for dir in files: 
        print (dir)
```

Comment: Y por qué usas `os.walk()` entonces si no estás interesado en los niveles inferiores? Usa `os.listdir()` que te dará sólo lo que hay en el primer nivel.

Comment: he actualizado mi código, solo me interesa que me imprima los archivos, los directorios no

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si sólo quieres mostrar los directorios de una carpeta dada, puedes usar `os.scandir()` pues aunque esta función te retorna todo, tanto ficheros como directorios, puedes después verificar si se trata o no de una carpeta antes de imprimirlo.

Por ejemplo:

```
for elemento in os.scandir(ruta):
  if elemento.is_file():
     print(elemento.name)
```

En cambio `os.walk()` es para otro cometido, en concreto listar *recursivamente* todo lo que hay en una carpeta hacia abajo, entrando en todos los subdirectorios que contenga.

Solo como curiosidad, se podría usar también `os.walk()`, aunque no tendría mucho sentido, si vacías la lista `dir` que te retorna (ya que esa lista es la que usará después para "seguir bajando"). Si esa lista está vacía, no seguirá descendiendo. Por tanto podrías hacer:

```
for root, dir, files in os.walk(ruta):
  # Imprimir la lista de ficheros
  for f in files:
     print(f)
  # Borrar la lista de directorios para que no descienda
  dir.clear()
```

Comment: El scandir es perfecto, cumple con lo que buscaba. Gracias.